# Testing $resource services in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am trying to begin writing unit tests for my angular application and hit a stopping block pretty quick as I am unsure of how exactly to mock my service in a testable way.
Is there a way to mock the REST call otherwise it would seem like I need to mirror everything within my service in my tests which doesn't seem right to me, but I am rather new to test writing so maybe this is how it is supposed to be accomplished.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My service is as follows:

```
angular.module('resources.users', ['ngResource'])
.factory('User', function($resource) {
   var resource = $resource('/api/index.php/users/:username', {}, {
      'update': {method: 'PUT'}
   });

   resource.getUser = function(username, successCb) {
      return resource.query({username: username}, successCb);
   };

   return resource;
});
```

My test consists thus far of:

```
describe('User', function() {
    var mockUserResource;
    beforeEach(module('resources.users'));
    beforeEach(function() {
        mockUserResource = sinon.stub({
            getUser: function(username) {
                mockUserResource.query({username: username});
            },
            query: function() {}
        });
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('User', mockUserResource);
        })
   });
   describe('getUser', function() {
      it('should call getUser with username', inject(function(User) {
          User.getUser('test');
          expect(mockUserResource.query.args[0][0]).toEqual({username: 'test'});
      }));
   })
});
```

Comment: Can you explain sinon.stub?

Comment: I used sinon originally to stub out functions but have since not used it as it doesn't seem to be needed.  ( http://sinonjs.org/ )

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can mock the requests made by ngResource like this:

```
describe('User', function () {
    var mockUserResource, $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            mockUserResource = $injector.get('User');
        })
    });

    describe('getUser', function () {
        it('should call getUser with username', inject(function (User) {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/index.php/users/test')
                .respond([{
                username: 'test'
            }]);

            var result = mockUserResource.getUser('test');

            $httpBackend.flush();

            expect(result[0].username).toEqual('test');
        }));

    });
});
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8FRBS/)**</kbd>

Comment: Awesome! What would I do without you for all my angular questions sza?

Comment: @Brian It is always good to figure out something together. :)

Comment: @sza +1 for this. I have a similiar question using JSONP in something a little more recent (Angular 1.2 and Karma 0.10.2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096300/testing-jsonp-resource-angularjs

Comment: The only issue with the test itself is that the value been asserted is the mocked data. result[0].username always will have the value of 'test' so it's kind of pointless. This test should be verifying if the $scope has been affected by the result.

Comment: I get "Unexpected request: GET "../../someTemplateURL.html" no more request expected if I add $httpBackend.flush(). Any ideas?

Comment: It's really bizarre that it's barfing on a request unrelated to my $resource.query(). and it only does this with flush command.

Comment: Great response. :)

Answer (score 31):

[zsong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18260036/833844) greatly helped me understand this, but I would like to expand on how it works. In case it gets edited, I list the code again here:

```
describe('User', function () {
    var mockUserResource, $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            mockUserResource = $injector.get('User');
        })
    });

    describe('getUser', function () {
        it('should call getUser with username', inject(function (User) {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/index.php/users/test')
                .respond([{
                username: 'test'
            }]);

            var result = mockUserResource.getUser('test');

            $httpBackend.flush();

            expect(result[0].username).toEqual('test');
        }));

    });
});
```

## What's going on here?

### 1

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));
```

We tell the Angular injector ([`$injector`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) and [`angular.mock.inject`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)) to inject things defined in the `myApp` module. You can think of it as defining a module dependency without a dependent module. Compare with how things defined in the `myApp` module can be injected in, say, a controller in a `angular.module('myOtherApp', ['myApp'])` module.

### 2

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        mockUserResource = $injector.get('User');
    })
});
```

Before each spec, run the `function ($injector)` function with dependencies injected. In this case, the dependency (`$injector`) is resolved implicitly from the parameter name. A functionally equivalent variant of this snippet is

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.inject(['$httpBackend', 'User', function ($httpB, User) {
        $httpBackend = $httpB;
        mockUserResource = User;
    }]);
});
```

Here we have instead declared the dependencies explicitly, and are free to use any parameter names we wish.

### 3

```
it('should call getUser with username', inject(function (User) {
```

Again, the test function is injected with the implicitly resolved `User` service as a parameter, though it isn't actually used.

Notice that this time there is no wrapper function around the `inject` call. `inject` invokes the passed function immediately if a spec is currently running, but otherwise it returns a wrapper function (see the inject [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) and [source code](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2211)), so we don't actually need the wrapper function. Thus, we could have written the `beforeEach` snippet above like this:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    mockUserResource = $injector.get('User');
}));
```