# testing JSONP $resource AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

How do I test a request being sent and data is being received with a JSONP service?

```
angular.module('search', [])
  .factory('SearchService', function($q,$rootScope,$resource) {
    var _search = {};
    _search.user = function(opts){
        return $resource('https://api.github.com/users/:user', {user: opts.user}, {
            search: {method:'JSONP',params:{callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}}
        });
    }
    return _search;
});
```

Following the GET request examples:

```
describe('search tests', function () {
    var svc, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function (){  
      module('ngResource');
      module('search');
      inject(function($httpBackend, SearchService) {
        svc = SearchService;      
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
      });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should send the message and return the response', function (){
        var returnData = { testing: 'anything'};
        httpBackend.expectJSONP('https://api.github.com/users/gigablox?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').respond(returnData);
        svc.user({user:'gigablox'}, function(user) {
            expect(user.testing).toEqual('anything');
        });
        httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

I can't seem to get by some errors:

- `Error: No pending request to flush !`
- `Error: Unsatisfied requests: JSONP`

*Using AngularJS 1.2 and Karma 0.10.2*

### Edit

Got it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/DhUqT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call your `search` like the following:

```
svc.user({user:'gigablox'}).search(function(user) {
    expect(user.testing).toEqual('anything');
});
```

The reason is the call to `svc.user()` returns a resource class object with a `search()` method. The `search()` method uses jsonp to make request. Without calling the `search()` method, $httpBackend will not see any request, so you see the errors mentioned in your question.

Comment: What is `svc.events`? I see only `svc.user` in your question

Comment: Typo sorry about that. `Error: Unexpected request: JSONP` is what I'm getting at the end of the day.

Comment: You'd better create a plunk to show the error you got, so I can see what you're doing more clearly.

Comment: You know what is strange is that I can't access the data returned in the callback. Using the resource `$promise` I can not `console.log` the returned value through `then()`. Could you please provide a fork from that fiddle to simply `console.log` out the data?