# AngularJS $resource service mocking, the right way

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

I am confused about the way AngularJS $resource service is supposed to be mokced for testing.
I found two ways to use $httpBackend service for it.
One way (taken from a Pluralsight tutorial):

```
describe('test', function() {

    beforeEach(module('name'));

    it('text', inject(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.expectGET("/url");
        // some code
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
}
```

An other way (copied from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258490/testing-resource-services-in-angularjs)):

```
describe('test', function () {
    var $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('name'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        })
    });

    describe('text', function () {
        it('text', inject(function (User) {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('/url')
                .respond([{
                    property: 'test'
                }]);

            // Some code

            $httpBackend.flush();
        }));

    });
});
```

I don't understand why the first way, uses *module* directly whereas the second way does *angular.mock.module*. And then the httpBackend service is injected so differently. The second way is so much more verbose. If the first way works, what's the point in all that verbosity of the second way?

Comment: `module` is a shortcut for `angular.mock.module`. The latter can be used to avoid conflict with CommonJS modules. `beforeEach` is used if the same services are supposed to be used in multiple specs.

Comment: Thanks. But as for _beforeEach_, I understand that but I don't understand why in the first case it's enough to use _inject(function($httpBackend)_ and in the second case, _angular.mock.inject(function ($injector)_ is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no right way, there are several different concerns here that should be kept in mind.

`module` is a shortcut for `angular.mock.module`. The latter can be used to avoid conflict with CommonJS modules.

The only reason why `angular.mock.inject` was used there is consistency with `angular.mock.module`, it can always be safely shortened to `inject`.

`beforeEach(inject(...))` is used if the same services are supposed to be used in multiple specs.

`beforeEach(function () { inject(...) })` is verbose version of `beforeEach(inject(...))`. If there should be something besides `inject` in `beforeEach` block, consider splitting it to several `beforeEach` blocks instead for readability.

`$injector.get` is just verbose and provides no benefits here in terms of style or features. It does nothing good if the services are variables, but it provides a useful pattern for assigning services in batch to `this` spec context without enumerating them several times:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
  var self = this;

  ['$httpBackend', ...].forEach(function (depName) {
    self[depName] = $injector.get(depName);
  });
}));

it(function () {
  var self = this;

  self.$httpBackend...
});
```